# Implementing a smart TicTacToe opponent

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner trying to create a tictactoe game in java, I need to create 2 specific methods, one where the opponent plays randomly and one where it plays aggressively and "smart", trying to actively win each turn.
  My problem comes with the actively playing method, as I have no clue how to start with this one.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Tictactoe
{
String table[][];    
boolean winner;
public Tictactoe()
{
    table = new String[3][3];
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            table[x][y] = " ";
            int xUser;
            int yUser;
            int xMac;
            int yMac;
        }
    }
}

public void board()
{ 
    System.out.println("-----------");
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {

        System.out.print("| ");
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {

            System.out.print(table[x][y] + " | ");
        }

        System.out.println();

    }
    System.out.println("-----------");
}

public void playRandom()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int xMaq;
    int yMaq;
    boolean winner = false;
    while(!winner)
    {
        move();                    
    }
    if(winner = true)
    {
        new Tictactoe();

}

public void findWinnerMach()
{
    if (table[0][0]== "O" && table[0][1]== "O" && table [0][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose");
        winner = true;       
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[1][0]== "O" && table[1][1]== "O" && table [1][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[2][0]== "O" && table[2][1]== "O" && table [2][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (tabla[0][0]== "O" && tabla[1][0]== "O" && tabla [2][0]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[0][1]== "O" && table[1][1]== "O" && table [2][1]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[0][2]== "O" && table[1][2]== "O" && table [2][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }        
    if (table[0][0]== "O" && table[1][1]== "O" && table [2][2]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[0][2]== "O" && table[1][1]== "O" && table [2][0]== "O") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You lose");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

public void findWinnerUser()
{
    if (table[0][0]== "X" && table[0][1]== "X" && table [0][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[1][0]== "X" && table[1][1]== "X" && table [1][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if (table[2][0]== "X" && table[2][1]== "X" && table [2][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[0][0]== "X" && table[1][0]== "X" && table [2][0]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
        winner = true; 
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[0][1]== "X" && table[1][1]== "X" && table [2][1]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
        winner = true
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[0][2]== "X" && table[1][2]== "X" && table [2][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[0][0]== "X" && table[1][1]== "X" && table [2][2]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (table[0][2]== "X" && table[1][1]== "X" && table [2][0]== "X") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!"); 
        winner = true;
        board();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void move()
{
    int xUser;
    int yUser;
    int xMac;
    int yMac;        
    xUser = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type a row from 0 to 2"));
    yUser = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type a column from 0 to 2"));       
    if(table[xUser][yUser] == "X" || tabla[xUser][yUser] == "O" ) {
        xUser = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Selected slot is taken, select a new row"));
        yUser = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Selected slot is taken, select a new column"));
    }
    else
    {
        table[xUser][yUser] = "X";
    } 
    table[xUser][yUser] = "X";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"CPU moves");
    xMac = (int)(Math.random()*3)+0;
    yMac = (int)(Math.random()*3)+0;      
    if(table[xUser][yUser] == "O" || table[xUser][yUser] == "X" ) {
        xUser = (int)(Math.random()*3)+0;
        yUser = (int)(Math.random()*3)+0;
        table[xUser][yUser] = "O";
    }              
    findWinnerUser();
    findWinnerMac();
    board();
}

public void playSmart()
{

}
}
```

It works, mostly, still lots to improve and need to touch up a few things, however, I don't want to do this until I have a set way, idea or plan to implement this "smart" method in case I'm horribly mistaken so far, would appreciate any help.

Comment: For a smart AI, you'll want to take a look at the [minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Pseudocode). There are more advanced algorithms too, but in the case of Tic Tac Toe this will already be sufficient for an optimal player (who never loses), and this algorithm will probably be easier to understand than more advanced ones (such as negamax, alpha-beta pruning, ...)

Comment: Btw, `if (winner = true)` is wrong, it should be `if (winner)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, "please help me" is not a question in the scope of this community. Having said that: one approach to such games is to first model all potential moves, to then determine the best move.

Comment: You should think about how you as a player would make the decision of which move to make and then think about how you can implement that in code. Your requirements are very broad/vague so it's hard to provide a more specific answer - how smart does it need to be? Should the AI be smart enough to try to block its opponent or only smart enough to line up its moves to get 3 in a row?